# Looping if statement on pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

I have a df made of three columns (A, B, C), each containing simple digits. 
I want to check if some elements in A and B add up to an element in C (A+B = C) and return the A, B elements that satisfy he condition. I am using the following code:

```
EW_sum = []
for i in df['A']:
    for j in df['B']:        
        if (i+j) in df['C']:
            x = (i, j)
            EW_sum.append((x))
```

However, the code is not looping over all the elements in A and B; it only giving me the first case where A+B = C and then abort. What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Based on your problem statement I think you could simply do `df.loc[df['A'] + df['B'] == df['C']][['A', 'B']]`

Comment: @0x5453 actually OP's logic in the code is different.

Comment: @QuangHoang True, but he also said that the code is incorrect, so I'm going purely off of the description.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is that `x in y` where y is a pandas `DataFrame` or `Series` checks whether `x` is in the *index* of `y`, not the values.

You can see this by looking at the docstring of `df.__contains__`, which is the method that is called when you call `x in df['C']`.:

```py
>>> help(df.__contains__)
Help on method __contains__ in module pandas.core.generic:

__contains__(key) method of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance
    True if the key is in the info axis
```

You could fix your code by changing to the line `if (i + j) in df['C'].values`, which accesses the numpy array holding the data in column C and calls *its* `__contains__` method.

For a small DataFrame this will not matter, but for large datasets checking `x in df['C'].values` (or using the pandas `contains` method, with `df['C'].contains(x).any()`) will be substantially faster than coercing your data to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this code instead. thanks

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    x = df['A'].iloc[i]
    y= df['B'].iloc[i]
    if x+y  in list(df['C']):
        EW_sum.append((x, y))
```

Comment: FYI, you should [avoid](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) looping over DataFrames.  See Michael's post for a vectorized solution which will be much faster.